# Using Sublime Text 2 with ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sublimetext2

I recently began a new job where we are using ASP.NET MVC 3 via Visual Studio 2010, but I'm seriously missing my Sublime Text 2! I'm primarily a Mac/Linux developer so I'm not super familiar with the build system for apps like this, but I was wondering if anyone could point me in the direction of some resources for setting up Sublime to work with my MVC3 Project.

Thanks! Any help would be very appreciated

Comment: As tempting as it can be for many of us, do your best not to get attached to this tool or that. The best tool for the job is probably going to be VS in this case. Embrace it and live in joy :)

Comment: You can code with Sublime and VS, even Notepad++ at the same time, is just about your preferences, I code C# in VS but when I move to the web stack I use sublime, I found Nader question appropiate

Comment: I too work in both Visual Studio (for Backend Development) and Sublime  (for Frontend Development) and trying to simply have better syntax in Sublime for Razor files. Although not perfect I found the following useful: https://github.com/joseph-turner/Razor